# ASP.NET Core 2.1 application ignoring request timeout defined in web configuration

Tags: iis, settimeout, asp.net-core-2.1

I need to set request timeout on .net core application (version 2.1) hosted on *iis*. I set "requesttimeout" in web configuration file, but it is ignored. I tried settings on *iis* but without any luck. Is there a way to solve this problem? I found information that "requesttimeout" is ignored for inProcess model in .net core version 3, but not in 2.1.

Comment: Is your issue solved? If your issue is solved then I request you to mark the helpful suggestion as an answer. This will help other people who face the same issue. If your issue still exists then try to refer the solution given by the community members. If then also you have any further questions then let us know about it. We will try to provide further suggestions to solve the issue. Thanks for your understanding.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the Microsoft document you can set the timeout value to the .net core 2.1 or later but it will not work with in-process hosting. For in-process hosting, the module waits for the app to process the request.

you could refer to this below link:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/aspnet-core-module?view=aspnetcore-3.1

you can set the value as suggested below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
 <system.webServer>
  <handlers>
   <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" 
        modules="AspNetCoreModule" 
        resourceType="Unspecified"/>
  </handlers>
  <aspNetCore requestTimeout="00:20:00" 
              processPath="%LAUNCHER_PATH%" 
              arguments="%LAUNCHER_ARGS%" 
              stdoutLogEnabled="false" 
              stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" 
              forwardWindowsAuthToken="false"/>
 </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: I've found this solution, but my app  is using iis. Is it possible that there is no solution to set request timeout when working with in-process hosting?

Comment: @Vanessa you could try to set the iis execution timeout value by using iis advance setting-> limit-> connection timeout [image](https://i.imgur.com/pVA26KH.png). Specifies the duration for which the ASP.NET Core Module waits for a response from the process listening on %ASPNETCORE_PORT%.
refer to this link for more detail: [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/aspnet-core-module?view=aspnetcore-2.1#attributes-of-the-aspnetcore-element-2)

Comment: tere is no option such as connection timeout in iis 6 (site advanced settings).

Comment: @Vanessa you are using iis 6?

Comment: @Vanessa For IIS 6.0 :
1.On the Web server, click Start, point to Control Panel, point to Administrative Tools, and then click Internet Information Services (IIS) Manager.
2.Expand the local computer node, expand Web Sites, right-click the appropriate Web site, and then click Properties.
3.Click the Web Site tab.
4.In the Connections area, change the value in the Connection timeout field, and then click OK.

Comment: Timeout is already set to 60 seconds, but it doesnt' work.

Comment: @Vanessa which os you are using?

Comment: I'm using windows 10.

Comment: @Vanessa could you try to host the site in iis 10 and set the connection time out value in site?